# Is a std::vector lookup faster than performing a simple operation?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to optimize some C++ code for speed, and not concerned about memory usage. If I have some function that, for example, tells me if a character is a letter:

```
bool letterQ ( char letter ) {
    return (lchar>=65 && lchar<=90) ||
       (lchar>=97 && lchar<=122);
}
```

Would it be faster to just create a lookup table, i.e.

```
int lookupTable[128];
for (i = 0 ; i < 128 ; i++) {
    lookupTable[i] = // some int value that tells what it is
}
```

and then modifying the letterQ function above to be

```
bool letterQ ( char letter ) {
    return lookupTable[letter]==LETTER_VALUE;
}
```

I'm trying to optimize for speed in this simple region, because these functions are called a lot, so even a small increase in speed would accumulate into long-term gain.

EDIT:

I did some testing, and it seems like a lookup array performs significantly better than a lookup function if the lookup array is cached. I tested this by trying

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
      if ( lookupfunction( text[i] ) )
      // do something
}
```

against

```
bool lookuptable[128];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 128 ; i++) {
    lookuptable[i] = lookupfunction( (char)i );
}

for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
    if (lookuptable[(int)text[i]])
        // do something
}
```

Turns out that the second one is considerably faster - about a 3:1 speedup.

Comment: Why not try both and measure the results?  It's the only way to be sure it is faster for your scenario on your target platform.

Comment: The sad scenario I'm in right now is that I have no idea what the platform is. I think it really boils down to instruction-level parallelism - depending on how the ILP is on the platform, the boolean function will take different runtimes. But good plan to test it, I'm just a lazy bum sometimes and appreciate StackOverflow answers over my own empirical tests :)

Comment: Without knowing the platform I think its impossible to reliably optimize at this level.

Answer (score 7):

About the only possible answer is "maybe" -- and you can find out by running a profiler or something else to time the code. At one time, it would have been pretty easy to give "yes" as the answer with little or no qualification. Now, given how much faster CPUs have gotten than memory, it's a *lot* less certain -- you can do a *lot* of computation in the time it takes to fill one cache line from main memory.

Edit: I should add that in either C or C++, it's probably best to at least start with the functions (or macros) built into the standard library. These are often *fairly* carefully optimized for the target and (more importantly for most people) support things like switching locales, so you won't be stuck trying to explain to your German users that 'ß' isn't *really* a letter (and I doubt many will be much amused by "but that's really *two* letters, not one!)

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume you have profiled the code and verified that this particular function is consuming a noticeable amount of CPU time over the runtime of the program?

I wouldn't create a vector as you're dealing with a very fixed data size. In fact, you could just create a regular C++ array and initialize is at program startup. With a really modern compiler that supports array initializers you even can do something like this:

```
bool lookUpTable[128] = { false, false, false, ..., true, true, ... };
```

Admittedly I'd probably write a small script that generates out the code rather then doing it all manually.

Comment: Good point, I just had a bunch of vectors elsewhere in my code so I had the word "vector" on my mind - I meant to say array.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple calculation like this, the memory access (caused by a lookup table) is going to be more expensive than just doing the calculation every time.

Comment: If the entire look-up table entry is in the cache, it is possible it may be faster than doing the calculation.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the calculation, the size of the lookup table and what other memory accesses your program might be doing. As others have mentioned, the way to find out is to profile your program.

Comment: Okay crazy twist- if I'm running this in parallel with OpenMP, should I expect cache coherency?

Comment: Assuming this is a read-only lookup table, there shouldn't be any issues with cache coherency.